# How to start animation of MotionLayout when something is happened?

Tags: motion, onbackpressed, android-motionlayout

I have got MotionLayout with motions of each view in it. All motions are working fine. I want to start motioning when onBackPressed() method is called or some button is clicked just like YouTube. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MotionLayout has methods to drive the animation.
things like motionLayout.[transtionToState](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#transitionToState(int))(...)

Comment: Thanks. There are also methods motionLayout.transitionToEnd and motionLayout.transitionToStart which have no parameters.